# Multiple Users in the Keychain

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keychain

so I got my iPhone app to use the keyChain and store my password.

```
KeychainItemWrapper *kc = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"Password"];
[kc SetObject:@"My_Password" forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccessGroup];
[kc release];
```

This saves my password correctly.
I tried to pass a string (username) instead of (id)kSecAttrAccessGroup to relate the password to a specific username, but It crashes.

**QUESTION: How can i relate the stored password to a username, because my app allows multipple user to login.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's not really an answer to your quesiton. But I use `SFHFKeychainUtils`([Github](https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security/)).

It's also a wrapper and it allows you exactly what you are looking for. Store a password associated to a username. Here's some code how I did it with SFHFKeychainUtils.

```
NSString *username = @"Username";
NSString *password = @"Password";
[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:username andPassword:password forServiceName:@"Your App" updateExisting:YES error:NULL];
```

Or pass an pointer to a `NSError` object if you want any error information. ;-)
I hope my answer will help you...

Sandro Meier